# PayPal PayFlow Pro - Credit Card Verification : CVV2 & BILLTOZIP

Tags: paypal, payflowpro

I using Paypal / Payflow Pro's Authorization transaction (TRXTYPE=A) to validate credit card information. I am passing 0.00 as the AMT. This works fine and can filter out wrong account number as well as card expiration date, paypal returns "RESPMSG=Invalid......".

However, the problem is in verifying both CVV2 and BILLTOZIP. When passing wrong values for these two paypal still returns "RESPMSG=Approved".

I am missing something? 
Can we validate CVV2 and BILLTOZIP on paypal? 
Is there another method that I can use for this?

I am using this request:

```
USER=XXXXXX&VENDOR=XXXXXXXX&PARTNER=PayPal&PWD=XXXX&TRXTYPE=A&TENDER=C&ACCT=4xxxx&EXPDATE=xxxx&CVV2=xxx&AMT=0&INVNUM=521aa62355f5eb5515eca3777e1f8b78&PONUM=PFDCCTEST&COMMENT1=Test Comment 1&COMMENT2=Test Comment2&VERBOSITY=HIGH&BILLTOFIRSTNAME=Frank
&BILLTOLASTNAME=Enstien&BILLTOSTREET=123 Main St.&BILLTOSTREET2=Suite 267&BILLTOCITY=GILBERT
&BILLTOSTATE=AZ&BILLTOZIP=85298&INVNUM=InvoiceNumber001&CUSTOM=CustomNumber001
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this live or sandbox?

> paypal still returns "RESPMSG=Approved

Check the rest of the return for =N , =X, other documented invalid value

If you still have issues post a full return string.

Comment: Thanks, even though they approve they also returned what is wrong. But sometimes they do not approve the request, weird.
CVV2MATCH = X
AVSZIP = X
AVSADDR = X

Comment: CVV2 and AVS verification are auxiliary checks. They are not required for a credit card transaction to be successful. Credit card card processing (and the Payflow gateway, which you are using), each both existed before those checks (CVV2 and AVS) existed.

Comment: In doing direct credit card processing, the expected pattern is for you to manage your own risk, examine the =X or otherwise responses yourself, and make your own determination about whether or not you are going to send the delayed capture attempt (`TRXTYPE=D`) for each successful TRXTYPE=A.  Although one for 0.00 is less useful.

Comment: Thanks! CVV2MATCH is X when wrong code is entered. However, there AVSZIP always is Y. This only happens on a CC from US. I tried using a CC from a different country and it is good.

Comment: Created another question for this issue. Thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61682063/paypal-payflow-pro-credit-card-verification-billtozip-avszip