# PayPal PayFlow Pro - Credit Card Validation : BILLTOZIP / AVSZIP

Tags: paypal, payflowpro

I am using Paypal / Payflow Pro's Authorization Transaction (TRXTYPE=A) to validate credit card information. I am passing 0.00 as the AMT.

This works fine and can filter out wrong account number, expiration date as well as wrong CVV2 code by checking CVV2MATCH = X in the return string.

However, there is a problem with BILLTOZIP validation. Return value is always AVSZIP = Y even if I entered the wrong ZIP.

What's weird is... The CC used for this transaction is from US. I used a CC from Philippines and wrong ZIP was being recognized.

Request:

```
USER=XXXXXX&VENDOR=XXXXXXXX&PARTNER=PayPal&PWD=XXXX&TRXTYPE=A&TENDER=C&ACCT=4xxxx&EXPDATE=xxxx&CVV2=xxx&AMT=0&INVNUM=521aa62355f5eb5515eca3777e1f8b78&PONUM=PFDCCTEST&COMMENT1=Test Comment 1&COMMENT2=Test Comment2&VERBOSITY=HIGH&BILLTOFIRSTNAME=Frank
&BILLTOLASTNAME=Enstien&BILLTOSTREET=123 Main St.&BILLTOSTREET2=Suite 267&BILLTOCITY=GILBERT
&BILLTOSTATE=AZ&BILLTOZIP=WRONGZIP&INVNUM=InvoiceNumber001&CUSTOM=CustomNumber001
```

Response:

```
RESPMSG = Verified: 10574-This card authorization verification is not a payment transaction.
CVV2MATCH = Y
HOSTCODE = 10574
PPREF = 3W881699AN973501D
CMD = curl ....................
IAVS = N
AUTHCODE = 111111
PROCAVS = Y
EXPDATE = 1024
PROCCVV2 = M
RESULT = 0
*AVSZIP = Y
TRANSTIME = 2020-05-08 07:40:45
AMT = 0.00
AVSADDR = Y
ACCT = 4009
CARDTYPE = 3
LASTNAME = NotProvided
PNREF = BE3P2D87ADA0
CORRELATIONID = 009e1072457da
```

Answer (score 0):

> BILLTOZIP=WRONGZIP

Is that the actual value you provided? Try `99999`